# How to build package.json for jquery

Tags: jquery, npm

I am new to Typescript and I would like to install `jquery.d.ts` so that I can use jQuery in my .ts files.  To get jquery.d.ts, I installed npm and then issued the command `npm install jquery`.  This resulted in the following error:

> npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Users\darli\package.json'

I also tried issuing the following command but getting the same result:

```
npm install --save @types/jquery
```

After searching for a resolution, I now understand that I need the package.json file to tell npm what to install.  I tried running `npm init` and this results in npm asking me questions about the package I want to install.  I found the actual file on GitHub but it is asking me to give it the entry point in another file called index.js and I do not know how to answer the question.

Can anyone help me create the package.json file or point me to a resource that explains how to do this?  It would seem to me that this package.json file should be easy to put together since jquery is very popular but I just cannot seem to get my hands around it.

Comment: Before using `npm` in your project, you should run `npm init` from the root of your project. It appears that you’re running in your home directory, so you should create a new directory for this specific project if you haven’t yet.

Comment: Thank you for responding but honestly, I do not understand your answer.  I am not trying to create a package, I just want to install jquery.d.ts.

Comment: The concept of project and package are one and the same for `npm`.

Comment: OP is apparently asking about Nugget(?), this question is tagged incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run the command `npm init` then you can install the jQuery package as you need.

Once you've ran `npm init` you will see a new file in your directory labeled package.json - this is the file that saves various information about your NPM related data. You should then be able to run your command `npm install --save @types/jquery` without any errors.

For more information on this process, checkout https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init

Comment: Thank you Adam for your response.  I managed to cobble a package.json file together based on the information I found here:

Comment: And then used npm install --save @types/jquery to install the thing.  It ran without error but nothing was added to the target directory. C:\Users\darli\AppData\Roaming\npm\.  This process is not straightforward.  Doesn't this sort of undo the reason Nuget was developed?

Comment: Your question was about NPM - if you need help with another environment, you should add the proper tags. Your question doesn't indicate that's what your platform is.

Comment: OK, I am trying to use npm to get a jquery.d.ts file using Windows 10 and Visual Studio.  How do I do that?  That is the problem.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: I would edit your question to include that relevant information. I've edited the tags to include Nugget, otherwise, I'm not familiar with the systems.